# L Shaped floating shelf of custom length

Tags: shelving

I need to get an L-shaped floating shelf of custom length. It shall go into the corner where my WFH desk exists. Most floating shelves I get are quite small. I need something that is 1m on one side and 2m on the other side.

I looked for website from which I can buy custom length floating shelf but the cost is several hundreds of £. It is basically unbelievable. Is it possible to make own custom L shaped floating shelf of this size at reasonable price?

Comment: How about two Lack wall shelves from Ikea?

Comment: What is a Lack wall shef?

Comment: Go to your region's Ikea website and enter "lack wall shelf" in the search box...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Depending on the tools you have access to and the level of skill you have one could build a rudimentary one in a day with access to a table saw, drill and a finish nailer.

A cleat made of a simple 2x3 screwed on edge to the wall with structural screws or lags would hold the shelf up or a store bought bracket would suffice, it depends on your budget and what you are putting on the shelves.

The shelf itself would be hollow, a simple box made of plywood or MDF, whichever you choose and would be fastened to the bracket using screws.

Without knowing your exact requirements, skills and available tools it's hard to determine exactly which route to go.

Here is a link to an article/plans on how to build a custom one by *This Old House*

[Floating Shelf Plans](https://www.thisoldhouse.com/house-one/21219396/diy-floating-shelves)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is "floating" - appearing to have no visible means of support.

With heavy duty shelf brackets it's trivial. Pile books and computers, climb on it to reach the ceiling, sit on it, no problem.

To make it "float" and actually carry significant loads while having no visible brackets is a rather different problem, or else you accept that someone leaning on it, or setting something heavy on it may bring the whole thing crashing down.

So, commercial solutions that don't want to be known for shelves crashing down when used normally have to manage great strength in a manner that's not structurally efficient. That gets expensive.

Comment: I see, but floating shelves are thick because they have support system inside (hidden), they have a lot of holes into the wall that is supporting the weight. I am sure there must be a way to calculate how many screws into masonry are required to support a certain amount of weight for certain depth of the shelf

Comment: There is a way to calculate: https://2.bp.blogspot.com/AG5uirTppuR1_bsMXfe5yztONY3O1YelST4aedxVrFADdLD-tWYVCN3ZGntcPq3LlMW0YTRPAtdX=s1600

Comment: It does not explain any method. Different type of walls dry wall, wood, masonry can support certain amount of weight before it breaks and the shelf fails. If I use more screws then it should be able to support more weight. So the basic idea is, how to calculate what is the worst case weight that must be not be exceeded to prevent failure of the floating shelf.